# How show different random Image with button without restarting the page?

Tags: javascript, html, image, random, directory

i want my popup (when a button is clicked) to show a random image out of my folder each time i click the button. I used html, css and javascript for my website.

**The problem:** it is the same random image each time. Only if i restart the page a different random image is showed.

**What works right now:** when i click the start-button a popup with a random image from that folder shows up (just how i want it) but if i click the close-button on my random picture and press the start-button again the same picture pops up again. Only if i restart my page then a new random picture will show when i press the start-button. But that picture stays the same, when i close the popup and want to start it again.

**I want a random image everytime when i press the start-button without having to restart the page.**

Do i use a boolean in javascript? Can i restart the function on its own? I have seen similar questions all the time but none of the solutions have worked for me kinda.

(the start-button is also a picture but it is a button) Sorry if the code is weirdly formatted, i am new to code <3

Thank you!!

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="popup" id="popup-1">
    <div class="overlay"> </div>
    <div class="content">
        <img class="imagelook"/> <!-- image is start-button -->
        <div 
        class="close-btn"
        onclick="togglePopup()"  
        onclick="generateRandomPicture(array)">&times; <!-- random image from folder -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<body>
<button type="button" onclick="togglePopup()" class="imglook"></button> <!-- the start-button -->
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
 function togglePopup(){
    document.getElementById("popup-1").classList.toggle("active");  
}

const imageArray =[
    "zettel/9.png",
    "zettel/8.png",
    "zettel/10.png",
    "zettel/11.png",
    "zettel/12.png",
    "zettel/13.png"
];

const image = document.querySelector("img");
    
window.onload = () => generateRandomPicture(imageArray);

function generateRandomPicture(array){
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length); 
    image.setAttribute("src", imageArray[randomNum]);
    }
```

Comment: the `div` element **must** be within the `body` - unless the above are simply extracts then that markup is invalid

Comment: Also - you may assign many event handlers but you cannot use multiple `onclick` definitions within the HTML

Comment: somehow the program doesnt work when i put the div in the body, but thanks i will try somehow!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following *might* help - coded to allow for multiple `popup` elements in conjunction with multiple `button` elements to trigger the display of different images in the respective `popup` div

```js
const images = [
  "zettel/9.png",
  "zettel/8.png",
  "zettel/10.png",
  "zettel/11.png",
  "zettel/12.png",
  "zettel/13.png"
];

const _CN='active';


const bttnclickhandler=function(e){
  // generate random image based upon array
  let imgsrc=images[mt_rand(0,images.length-1)];
  // assign image the new src
  this.previousElementSibling.querySelector('img').src=imgsrc;
  this.previousElementSibling.classList.add(_CN);
  console.info(imgsrc)
};

const closeclickhandler=function(e){
  e.target.closest('.popup').classList.remove(_CN);
  this.previousElementSibling.src='';
  console.clear();
};

// generate a random number between a & b
const mt_rand=(a,b)=>Math.floor( Math.random() * ( b - a + 1 ) + a );


// assign listeners to all pertinent elements
document.querySelectorAll('button.imglook').forEach(n=>n.addEventListener('click',bttnclickhandler));
document.querySelectorAll('div.close-btn').forEach(n=>n.addEventListener('click',closeclickhandler));

document.querySelectorAll('div.popup').forEach(n=>{
  n.querySelector('img').src=images[mt_rand(0,images.length-1)]
})
```

```css
.active{background:pink}
.popup{margin:1rem;}
.imglook{padding:1rem}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <img class="imagelook" />
    <div class="close-btn">&times;</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="imglook"></button>



<div class="popup">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <img class="imagelook" />
    <div class="close-btn">&times;</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="imglook"></button>
```